# How to parse unquoted json string in dart [flutter]

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this string:

```
String data = "{connected: true, size: 12}";
```

I'd like to parse it into a `Map<String, dynamic>`

I tried

```
Map<String, dynamic> map =  json.decode((data));
```

I have this exception

> FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 2)`

Comment: Are you getting `data` string dynamically/from the server or you have it hard coded and want to decode it?

Comment: I'm getting it from the server

Comment: string needs to look like this `{"connected": true, "size": 12}` to decode it in a map.

Comment: I updated the string coming from the server. It's working fine now

Answer (score -1):

try this...  `Map map =  json.decode((data));`
dynamic type auto assign when you parse inside your Function...
Or Remove the `Map<String, dynamic>` from you function too.